# COUNT for each province always failed everytime applying WHERE clause

Tags: sql

so i need to count how many customer that inactive on each province, however it always 'query has no results' everytime i set up the filter using where clause.. anyone knows how to escape from this issue?

```
SELECT a.province, count(t.customer_id) as total_customer_on_each_province

FROM total_customer t
LEFT JOIN last_address a on a.customer_id = t.customer_id

WHERE t.status = 'INACTIVE'
GROUP BY province
```

Comment: Please try to start with SELECT COUNT(T.CUSTOMER_ID),T.STATUS FROM TOTAL_CUSTOMER AS T GROUP BY T.STATUS to see the existing statuses

Comment: You're using a `where` applied to the right hand table, which essentially makes it an inner join. Use it in the `on` clause for left join functionality

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It is quite unusual to aggregate by a column in the *second* table of a `left join`.  The error suggests that there are no rows where the condition is true.  One possibility (in some databases) is case-sensitivity.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.